# How to compare <option> “data-names” in an “if” statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a slight issue. I have options with a “value” and a “data-name”.

```
<option value=”A” data-name1=”X”>
<option value=”B” data-name1=”Y”>
```

I want the computer return a specific value if the selected option is a certain “data-name”

Say there are 2 “data-names”, X and Y.

How can I compare the data-name of the selected option to the 2 data-names, X and Y, to find out which one it is?

I’m thinking something along the lines of this:

---

```
var data_name1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].dataset.name1; 

if (data_name1 == “X”) {
…
}
else if (data_name == “Y”) {
…
}
else {
…
}
```

---

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Full code---

```html
<script>
document.getElementById("selectElement").selectedIndex = -1; // so that no option //is selected when the page is loaded


function getData(){
  var e = document.getElementById("qwert"); // get the <select> element

  var data_name1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].dataset.name1; // get the selected //<option> and its name1 data attribute

  

 // var data_name2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].dataset.name2;  get the selected //<option> and its name2 data attribute

 

  var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; // get the value of the selected <option>


//Result
document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML = data_name1;
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = value;  
}
</script>











<select id="qwert" onclick="getData ()">
<option value="135" data-name1="M">A</option>
            <option value="150" data-name1="R">B</option>
            <option value="51" data-name1="R">C</option>
            <option value="27" data-name1="M">D</option>
</select>

<p>
  <label>data-name1 = </label>
  <span>"</span><span id="data1"></span><span>"</span>
</p>



<p>
  <label>value = </label>
  <span>"</span><span id="value"></span><span>"</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `==`  operator to compare objects.

`=` is an assignment expression.

```
if (data_name1 == “X”) {
   // Operations if data_name is equal to X
}
else if (data_name == “Y”) {
  // Operations is data_name is equal to Y
}
else {

}
```